# Compiling Windows C++ application with long doubles in VS2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, precision, long-double

At work we have MSVS2010 Ultimate, and I'm writing a program which runs exhaustive simulations using real numbers. I'm getting non-trivial round-off errors and I've already taken reasonable steps to ensure my algorithm is as numerically stable as possible.

I'd like to switch to 128-bit quadruple precision floating point numbers (long double, right?), to see how much of a difference it makes.

I've replaced all relevant instances of `double` with `long double`, recompiled, and ran my dummy simulation again but have *exactly* the same result as before.

These are my (debug) compiler options as per my project property page in C/C++:

/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug\FFTU.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

My dev CPU is a Core2 Duo T7300 but the target machine will be an i7. Both installations are Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: With Visual C++, `long double` is the same as `double`, hence why the result is the same  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I see. Is there any other way to get 128-bit quadruple precision in VS2010 in Windows? (without using any 3rd party libraries like GMP. Windows.h is ok though).

Comment: Do you think your CPU provides 128-bit floating point?  x87 only supports 32, 64, and 80 bits (I'm not an expert on the subject, but I don't think SSE provides any uberwise floating point capabilities either).

Comment: The reply above isn't really fair.  C++ libraries used to work with floating point even when an 8087 co-processor wasn't present.  So with this in mind, another solution would be to find a math library that allows the precision you want.  It would be an awful lot slower, but at least it would work.

Comment: Your problem most likely be solved with a wider float.

Comment: @Robinson Yes, I was a little confused by the comment. I remember doing 64-bit double-precision stuff back on my 386 which didn't have any 64-bit hardware; and `long double` has been part of C since 1989. I don't think software libraries are really suitable since they have a tremendous affect on performance, which is crucial in my application. I will try GCC and 80-bit extended precision like wallyk suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch to a non-Microsoft compiler such as `gcc`, Borland, or Intel.  Those all recognize `long double` as 80-bit extended precision, the native internal format of the 8087.

Comment: On gcc-4.3.4 `sizeof(long double)` is 12. [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/TLbiS). VC++ `doubles` use 80-bit registers to hold the intermediate results of floating-point calculations, but are stored with 64-bits in memory.